# get list of all db query in codeigniter (in ajax request)

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I'm using codeigniter

now my ajax request its very slow and I want to find the reason

in ajax request, I want to save all DB query in a log file

it's possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can turn on db loging in config file:

```
$db['default'] = array(
   ...
   'save_queries' => TRUE
   ....
);
```

then end of ajax request use `$queries = $this->db->queries;` to get all SQL query

```
$log .= join("\n",$this->db->queries);
$myfile = file_put_contents('logs.txt', $txt.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just enable slow query log on database. E.g. on MySQL:

```
SET GLOBAL slow_query_log = 'ON';
SET GLOBAL long_query_time = X;
SET GLOBAL slow_query_log_file = '/path/filename';
```

**X** - it logs any query that takes longer than X seconds to run. Default value is 10 seconds.

**/path/filename** - A path for log file. Default value is `/var/lib/mysql/{hostname}-slow.log`